# Help Translate Chinese Seals (Characters identified: 袁珮珞 玉芹)

Tags: character-identification, seal

I am trying to get a translation on the seal to determine the artist's name. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The artist's name is 「袁珮珞」 (Mandarin Pinyin: **Yuán Pèiluò**), and 「玉芹」 (**Yù Qín**) is probably the artist's [art name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_name).

There's not much information on this artist that I can find; a quick search only reveals that the artist has [one painting being sold in an auction at SoWAs](https://sowas-group.com/auctions/item/13780?currency_unit=JPY).

[image: 袁珮珞]

> 袁珮珞

[image: 玉芹]

> （玉）芹